# How to hide checkboxes for user authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, cancancan

Good day, I am using the CanCanCan gem, an authorization library for Ruby on Rails which restricts what resources a given user is allowed to access.  It is working however when users sign up, all of the options including 'admin' and 'banned' show up.  I want to hide those two checkboxes and leave 'customer' and 'sitter'.  How would I do that?

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ROLES = %i[admin sitter customer banned]

  def roles=(roles)
    roles = [*roles].map { |r| r.to_sym }
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.inject(0, :+)
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject do |r|
      ((roles_mask.to_i || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
    end
  end

  def has_role?(role)
    roles.include?(role)
  end
```

edit.html.erb

```
        <% for role in User::ROLES %>
          <%= check_box_tag "user[roles][#{role}]", role, @user.roles.include?(role), {:name => "user[roles][]"}%>
          <%= label_tag "user_roles_#{role}", role.to_s.humanize %><br />
        <% end %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]", "" %>
      </div>
      </div>
```

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Answer (score 0):

Allowing users to set their own roles is probably a bad idea, even for non-privileged roles.

Just guessing by context, you're working on a childcare application, where users can sign up as customers or as sitters. You should set up your checkboxes manually, rather than building them based on your `@roles` array list, or you can create a `@public_roles` array for use in your views that only includes non-admin roles.

Finally, for some reason, you have a role called 'banned' which technically isn't a role -- it's a user state which should be dealt with separately.

Answer (score 0):

In edit.html.erb replace `for role in User::ROLES` with `for role in %i[customer sitter]`

You should consider the possibility that a malicious user may also craft their own checkbox for one of the protected states (`admin` or `banned`). Make sure to build in protection to make sure users cannot set themselves to `admin` unless they are allowed to.